# Owlready2 optimized not available

Tags: python

I try to open the ontology with python but there is an error

here is the code:

```
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("http://www.lesfleursdunormal.fr/static/_downloads/pizza_onto.owl")
onto.load()
```

and here the error:

```
C:\Users\Khaoula\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/Khaoula/PycharmProject/project1/resume.py
* Owlready2 * Warning: optimized Cython parser module 'owlready2_optimized' is not available, defaulting to slower Python implementation
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there any solution?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Technically that isn't an error, just a warning. Your code finished with exit code 0 meaning success.

Comment: yes it is true, but when I want to add or modify a class or an instance in the ontology there remains the mm problem.

Answer (score 6):

[Reference](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Owlready2 include an optimized Cython module. This module speeds up by about 20% the loading of large ontologies, but its use is entirely optional. To build this module, you need a C compiler, and to install the ‘cython’ Python package.

Most linux systems comes with **C** compilers by default. For me just installing the Cython before installing owlready2 has done the trick.

```
pip install Cython
pip install owlready2
```

For windows, download the **Cython** wheel file from the below link if **pip install Cython** failed

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#cython)

```
pip install Cython_wheel_file.whl
# Example
pip install Cython‑0.29.21‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl
```

---

Note: if you get following message installing owlready2

```
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
 ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for owlready2
  Running setup.py clean for owlready2
Failed to build owlready2
Installing collected packages: owlready2
    Running setup.py install for owlready2 ... done
Successfully installed owlready2-0.31
```

Then owlready2 is installed but if you don't want to get this error further,then uninstall owlready2 and install wheel package and reinstall owlready2

```
pip uninstall owlready2
pip install wheel
pip install owlready2
```

Comment: This seems to not work as of 5/4/2022 on windows 11 - owlready2 is not recognizing the cython installation and is not installing the C-optimized

Comment: Same on OS Ventura: installing with or without python does not change anything, the warning is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Using conda would be a simpler method.

```
conda install -c conda-forge owlready2
```

Search and you will find installation guild in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/owlready2

Comment: This does not work on OS X (Ventura): conda installation fails.